# Reporting Server error: cache refresh plans cannot be created or edited because the associated item has user profile dependencies

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I published my first report on Reporting server and I've tried to set a cache plan and I have the error

> cache refresh plans cannot be created or edited because the associated
>   item has user profile dependencies

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search I've found the problem was that the report contents the had a reference a the user profile property (as said the message) User!Language in a DataSet. For resolve I added a custom code that return the value runtime and replace the property with expression

> "=Code.GetLanguage()".

```
Funtion GetLanguage() as String
  return  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
End Function
```

Of course the problem occurs for any the user profile property  (User!XXX)